# Postgres Query with Date extraction

Tags: sql, datetime, psql

I have a table with a Date field called 'run_date' in which I need to perform the following task:

get the value which has the ((most up-to-date *year* AND *month*) AND the earlier *day*).

```
Example:

run_date
2012-12-24
2012-12-31
2013-01-03
2013-01-07
2013-01-14
```

I need a query that returns '2013-01-03', because it follows the rules above.
My best try is:

```
SELECT
    run_date as val
FROM
    myTable
    WHERE  to_char(run_date, 'MM'::text) = (SELECT MAX(EXTRACT ('MONTH' FROM run_date)) FROM myTable)
    and to_char(run_date, 'YYYY'::text) = (SELECT MAX(EXTRACT ('YEAR' FROM dado_dt_data_rodada)) FROM myTable)

    ORDER BY val ASC LIMIT 1
```

Of course, the months cycle between 1-12, so the query above doesn't work.
I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the earliest date in the most recent month.  Try this:

```
SELECT run_date as val
FROM myTable
ORDER BY to_char(run_date, 'YYYY-MM') desc, run_date asc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think it works! What i want is the *earliest date in the most recent month AND year*. So you first sort it by year-month DESC, then sort again by day ASC?

Comment: @Fernando . . . Yes, that is what this does.  The first part of the `order by` puts the most recent month at the top.  The second part puts the earliest date in the month.